What does the variable declaration `const int *__errno_location ()` inside this catch statement actually do?
While working on an exercise for my C++ class where we were working on Exception handling, I came across a puzzling issue. I initially had the following exception handler (Please don't roast the use of ints as exceptions, this was the task we were given):
#include <iostream>
//...

try {
    // Code that throws an int
}
catch(const int errno) {
    std::cout << errno << std::endl;
}

To the untrained eye, this would seem like a normal declaration of an integer exception variable. However, the unsafe code kept evading the catch block, despite throwing an integer itself. After some investigation, it turned out that a Macro in errno.h declared #define errno (*__errno_location ()) caused a Macro Expansion into the following code
try {
    // Code that throws an int
}
catch(const int (*__errno_location())) {
    std::cout << (*__errno_location()) << std::endl;
}

I was unsure what exactly is being declared in the catch Expression. I tried using C Gibberish to English, but unsurprisingly that didn't help much, telling me that it was declaring a function returning an int*. ChatGPT was also puzzled by this expression, calling it "unconventional formatting".
Playing around with it a little, I came up with the following code:
const int *blah() {
    return new int(10);
}

int main() {
    try {
        throw &blah;
    }
    catch(const int *foo()) {
        std::cout << *foo () << std::endl;
    }
}

Which outputs the number 10 to the console. Changing the values in the integer constructor also causes that integer to be output to the console as well. So my current hypothesis is that const int *foo() is declaring that a function pointer returning an int pointer be caught in this catch block, and in the print statement we simply call that function and dereference the pointer. I would like my hypothesis be verified or corrected by more experienced C++ programmers though.

The code should not have used the variable name errno.  It is a reserved name and it causes the side effects. Replace errno with a different variable name and you should fine. Also note it is recommended to catch exception types by const& (for int not so impotant). So use catch(const int& value) std::cout << value << "\n" and you should be fine.

Your research is correct. In C++ any type can be thrown, that includes functions and function pointers. You could make it more readable with using FuncType = const int *(); and catch (FuncType foo).

Invoking operator new in function blah leaks memory, as there is no corresponding delete to be found anywhere.

errno is implementation defined. See cppreference:

errno is a preprocessor macro used for error indication. It expands to a static(until C++11)thread-local(since C++11) modifiable lvalue of type int.

From what you already found out, we can conclude that __errno_location() is a function (or some callable) returning a pointer to int which encodes the last error on the implementation you are using.
As mentioned in a comment, the identifier errno is reserved by POSIX.
Now, what happens in your code is more or less this:
int* foo() { 
    static int x = 42;
    return &x;
}

int main() {
    try {

    } catch(const int (*foo()) ){

    }
}

Which also compiles (see here: https://godbolt.org/z/3v8nsPr74).
The reason is that const int (*foo()) is actually declaring a parameter named foo of type const int(*)(), ie a pointer to a function with no parameter and returning a const int.
And as you already discovered, the name is just coincidence. Your parameter is called __errno_location, and inside the catch block it shadows the actual function with the same name.
The lesson to learn here is how evil macros are. They pollute the global namespace. That's why you had the surprise when using errno as the name of the parameter. And secondly, macros are evil, because an innocent-looking name can turn a const int* into something of a totally different type. Unfortunately, here you have no choice to not use the macro. You only have to be careful to avoid the name.

@Yksisarvinen it compiles because *__errno_location() is a modifyable lvalue of type int.... oh ok now I get what you mean. How much i dislike to be accepted when I am wrong :/

Removed my comment, since OP accepted your answer, so I was interpreting it wrongly I guess.

@Yksisarvinen no I think you were right. I dont understand why the code compiles and I really wasnt answering that when writing this

Accepted the answer before I looked at the comments... So the mystery is not solved yet I assume? I am hesitating kind of to say we declared a function pointer variable because coming form C I expected the declaration to be return_type (*name)(args...) which is close to but not quite what the actual code expands to

@Keheck the part I dont understand yet is why this compiles https://godbolt.org/z/TaxWsv51c ? Perhaps simple, but I dont see it, and I have to leave, so I suggest you unaccept this for the moment

@Keheck IMO you wrote it in your question already - it is interpreted as function type, taking no arguments, returning const int* and such function object when caught is named __errno_location.

That is the theory based on the evidence yes, but I wonder why it can be declared that way. As I said, I expected the syntax to be const int* (*foo)() or something similar, since that's how you usually declare function pointers (in this case a function returning an int* with no arguments). Maybe I am missing a small detail from C++

@Keheck The detail may be that there are function types and function pointer types. It's highly confusing feature in language, since when you declare function type as parameter, you really get function pointer, and when you pass a function to other function, both foo and &foo get converted to function pointer. And calling function pointer doesn't require dereferencing pointer first...

Maybe my wording was a little unclear. What I meant was that we call the function foo and then dereference the int pointer that it returned.
I wonder, is the difference between function pointer types and function types a C++ feature or do function types exist in C as well? I know that it has function pointer types

@Keheck I edited again and imho now the answer is complete. However, all the parts are already present in your quesion. I am only reiterating what you already say.

It seems to be parsed as a function taking no parameters returning const int*: https://godbolt.org/z/hhx71jxrc (Note the catch is adjusted just like function parameters, so foo is declared with a function type and is adjusted to a pointer-to-function type)
